# Anko's uiThread sporadically not fired

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, anko

I am currently using Anko's *doAsync* to handle asyncronous tasks.
Specifically, i'm using it to parse a response *json* to an *ArrayList* of data objects, as seen below:

```
// Asynchronously parse server response
doAsync {
    val itemlist = parseResponse(response)
    uiThread {
        Otto.INSTANCE.post(UpdateRedeemedVoucherViewsEvent(itemlist))
    }
}
```

Most of the time, like on an **Google Pixel (Android 8.0.0)**, this works just fine. My objects get parsed, and the *Otto bus event* will be posten on the *ui thread*.

But in some rare cases, this process fails.
So far i noticed that the ui thread call wont be fired on an **Galaxy S5 Mini (Android 5.1.1)**. Although my data was parsed without any errors or exceptions, the code snippet in the *uiThread* brackets won't be executed.

So far i was not able to determine any reason for this behaviour. No logcat logs, nothing. There is no scheme of when this error will appear.

Has anybody had the same or a similar problem with kotlin and/or Anko?

**UPDATE: I've found a solution by myself, please see my answer below for an explanation.**

Comment: can you post your `parseResponse` code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your help guys.
I've figured it out by myself, so i'm posting this answer just in case anyone else faces this problem.

**TL;DR: the *context* gets lost, so the *uiThread* won't be executed**

Solution:
I've stumbled across this [post](https://antonioleiva.com/api-request-kotlin/) where an important feature of the *uiThread* method was mentioned:

> Basically you have an async function that will execute it’s code in another thread, and will give the chance of returning main thread using uiThread. async is an extension function implemented for Context, and will use a weak reference of it, so it won’t prevent GC from releasing its memory.

Upon further investigation, i've found the following log right after my parsing was done, and where the *uiThread* should have been called:

```
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 30879(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 16(2MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 16MB/27MB, paused 2.123ms total 196.372ms
```

So it seems that there is indeed some GC action, which may or may not the *context* to get freed.

To prevent this, i'm using Ankos **runOnUiThread**, which can be *called* on a given context reference:

```
// Asynchronously parse server response
doAsync {
    val itemlist = parseResponse(response)
    context.runOnUiThread {
        Otto.INSTANCE.post(UpdateRedeemedVoucherViewsEvent(itemlist))
    }
}
```

As far as i can tell by now, this seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Doing this, you are leaking your context instance. I'm not sure if it will free after this because of the lifecycle could not be destroying it properly, you know?

Comment: yeah, i'm aware of that. But this is, at the moment, the only way i can get this to be called consistently. I'll keep an eye on that and will report if it causes any further problems

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was because an uncaught exception is happening in background.

surround your background task with a try/catch and you should be able to see what is occurring.

```
doAsync {
    try {
        val itemlist = parseResponse(response)
    } catch(t: Throwable) {
        //TODO log your exception
    ]
    uiThread {
        Otto.INSTANCE.post(UpdateRedeemedVoucherViewsEvent(itemlist))
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Neither the _catch_ case nor the _uiThread_ will be entered